# Spark dataframe cube operation giving duplicate rows

Tags: apache-spark, aggregate-functions

I am doing a cube operation with count aggregation on a spark dataframe that has close to 1 million rows. I am using 4 columns for doing this cube operation. I notice that the dataframe returned after cube operation has duplicate rows. Specially for null combinations.

There are no nulls in my input DF since I have replaced all nulls with separate default values for each column before doing the cube operation.Also I am filtering out the rows of the cube output where by all 3 grouping columns are null, because that represent the total count and I am already aware of that.

An example could be :

```
val dimensions = List("A","B","C","D")
   
    val cube_df = input_df.cube(dimensions.head, dimensions.tail: _*)
   .count()
   .filter(!(col("A").isNull  && col("B").isNull && col("C").isNull && col("D").isNull))
```

now if a do a show on the cube like this :

```
   cube_df
    .filter(col("A").isNull && col("B").isNull && col("C").isNull && col("D") === "xyz")
    .show(false)

+----+----+----+---------------+-----------+
|A   |B   |C   |D              |Count      |
+----+----+----+---------------+-----------+
|null|null|null|xyz            |10221      |
|null|null|null|xyz            |232638     |
+----+----+----+---------------+-----------+
```

I see two rows in the output and obviously only 1 of these rows represent the correct count as per the input_df (the second row in my case).

I am also aware that cube basically does a group by of all combination 1 by 1 keeping non participating columns in any combination as null and keeps performing a union_all operation for each combination group by. But still this seems a little strange to me.

So why is this happening ? and If I cannot avoid this duplicate combination output,then how I Identify which of the returned combination represent correct output ?

Comment: Is the `cube_df` in the 2nd snippet _really the same_ as in the 1st snippet? Which Spark version are you using?

Comment: yes, my input_df contains 4 columns (A,B,C,D) and I am creating a cube_df using the input_df on all 4 columns. spark version is 2.4.1

Comment: Cannot reproduce with Spark 2.4.5 (and a much smaller data set). Can you provide a full example (using random data with a constant seed)? Either there is a bug in Spark or there is a bug in the lines we do not see here